# the experiment consisting of an infinite sequence of coin flips

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the experiment consisting of an infinite sequence of coin flips. Then 
$$\Omega = (w_1,w_2,\ldots): w_i\in \{0,1\} \ for \  i=1,2,\ldots  $$

For $A_k$, an set of $k-$dimensional vectors of $0´$s and $1´$s, we want
$$P(\{(w_1,w_2,\ldots): (w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_k)\in A_k\})=\frac{|A_k|}{2^k}$$

Let $X((1,1,1,1,\ldots))= \ inf\{i:w_i=0\}$, if  $w_i=0$ for some $i$, and
$$ X((1,1,1,1,\ldots))=23$$

Then I have proved that $X$ is a random variable. But How can I calculate the distribution?

Someone could help me with this or give me some hints please.

Comment: Hint: start with $P(X > k)$ for $k$ in ${\mathbb N}$, then ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: I was reading a book of probability to try solve this and I have a dude, What does it mean "a.s."? I´m trying to calculate the probability that you suggeted me but I don´t know how with the conditions given.

Comment: a.s. means *almost surely*, a synonym being *with probability* $1$. Try to describe the sequences $w$ that satisfy $X(w) > k$.

Comment: Ok, I´m trying, ty for the hint